# How to practically check whether server can handle many MySQL connections simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I am new at server-side scripting. On my website, I have MySQL database of users. My website is supposed to host an event where all the users will be logging in and answering some questions. So there will be a lot of MySQL queries submitted, to check whether what they have entered is correct or not. And in the event, the users can submit again and again until the answer is correct.

My question is, instead of going into the specifications of server to estimate the maximum concurrent MySQL connections, is there a way to practically get that? What I mean is, is there some way (some function or algorithm), which will put similar load on the server as number of users submitting queries simultaneously. Sort of like a test run. And in the test run, I should be able to know the maximum concurrent MySQL connections that the server can handle without crashing or slowing down.

I tried to understand [mysqlslap](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlslap.html), but I find it very difficult to understand. I have also visited 
[this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-measure-mysql-query-performance-with-mysqlslap), but that is on linux server. I am working with phpMyAdmin + MySQL. So is there any easy tutorial for phpMyAdmin somewhere? Or maybe someone can mention what to do shortly. Please consider that I am a newbie at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking two different kind of questions; what the maximum number of simultaneous mysql connections is and how you can stress-test your server.

The answer to the first question is easy, there is a mysql setting called `max_connections` that sets the maximum number of connections and you can check that in phpMyAdmin by going to the `Variables` tab and searching for `max connections`.

If you need to change that value you need to look for your config file. That can be for example `/etc/my.cnf` but that depends on the server and whether you are using MariaDB or MySQL.

When you stress-test your server, mysql will probably not be the problem, but things like memory, etc.

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain the difference between max connections and max user connections? Which one will be applied in my case of the event?

Comment: I realize now that my question was about simultaneous mysql connections rather than stress-testing. Thanks for replying. Can you explain the difference I mentioned in above comment?

Comment: @DarshilChauhan I have never done anything with the max user connections and I have never run into any limits there. I have run into problems because of a too low setting for `max_connections` and as that seems a lot lower than the other one, it seems the only relevant one :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the max connections with any SQL tool, using the query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
```